# Cloud functions for firebase - deleted or added data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to distinguish between deleted and data that was first created.
I´m using the code from Firebase:

```
if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }
  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!event.data.exists()) {
    return;
  }
```

However, it doesn't work. I´m listening to the database which is structured as following:

- in use

  - fruitID
  - id: fruitID

I want to use code when the data is deleted and another code when the data is created, so when a fruit is added.

Using the given code only the part in

```
if (event.data.previous.exists()){
}
```

is executed AND ALWAYS when the data is DELETED.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to think about this if you gave a complete and minimal sample of code (the entire function), along with a description of how it's not working the way you expect with given inputs and outputs

Comment: Also show what you are applying the listener to. Are you listening to the child node like `/fruits/{fruidID}/id` or the parent node `/fruits/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud functions has new triggers that you can use for this particular workflow.

> `onWrite()`, which triggers when data is created, destroyed, or changed in the Realtime Database.
>
> `onCreate()`, which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.
>
> `onUpdate()`, which triggers when data is updated in the Realtime Database.
>
> `onDelete()`, which triggers when data is deleted from the Realtime Database.

You could create two triggers, `onDelete` and `onCreate`.

Otherwise if you want to create it in one function you could setup a function using `onWrite`

```
export listener = functions.database.ref('/fruit/{fruitId}').onWrite(event => {
  if (!event.data.previous.exists()) {
    // Created Event - Previous data doesn't exist.
  } else if (!event.data.exists()) {
    // Deleted Event - Data doesn't exist.
  } else {
    // Update
  }
}
```